# using R ifelse() for defining colours in a plot

Tags: r

I need help in using the code below for defining a colour scheme in my graphical plot. I want both the elements with values x <= -2 | y > 2 to appear as red and the others black.

```
col = ifelse( x <= -2 | y > 2, "red", "black")
```

There is a problem with the logical OR part, and this results in errors. What is the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example that results on the error and give the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(100,-4,0)
y <- rnorm(100,mean=2)

plot(x,y,col=c("black", "red")[(x <= -2 | y > 2) + 1])
```

[image]

In your specific case, this would also work since 1 corresponds to black and 2 to red for colours in `plot`:

```
plot(x,y,col=(x <= -2 | y > 2) + 1)
```

However, your solution also works for me:

```
col = ifelse( x <= -2 | y > 2, "red", "black")
plot(x,y,col=col)
```

Comment: Many thanks Roland! It works now. I found the source of the problem. I appreciate the alternative solutions that you provided.

Comment: @user27976 please share your "source of the problem", also consider accepting as an answer and/or upvoting useful answers.

Comment: EDIT: The source of the problem was a loose extra "}" in another section of the code.